# Mui Autocomplete does not show loading spinner when loading is true

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Mui `Autocomplete` does not show loading spinner, although loading is set to `true`.
Does it have a loading state?

[image: Edit https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-109rj]

```
<Autocomplete
  loading
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works as intended. The loading component is [only rendered](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/4d78b4945024e451ba61b7f5748a29cdaa29794a/packages/material-ui/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L644) when `loading` is `true` **AND**  there is no filtered options in `Autocomplete`.

[image: Edit 66803107/mui-autocomplete-does-not-show-loading-spinner]